# .getElementById cannot find id in document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting up a webpage for a school competition and I want to write some code that when the mouse hovers over the footer, it will expand to full screen.

I have already written the code but one the JavaScript `.getElementById()` function cannot locate my footer with the id foot.

```js
const footer = document.getElementById("foot");


footer.addEventListener("mouseenter", fullscreen);
footer.addEventListener("mouseleave", original);


function fullscreen() {
    footer.classList.add("fullscreen");
    footer.classList.remove("original");
}

function original() {
    footer.classList.add("original");
    footer.classList.remove("fullscreen");
}
```

```css
@keyframes fullscreen {
    from {height: 10vh};
    to {height: 100vh};
}

@keyframes original {
    from {height: 100vh};
    to{height: 10vh};
}

.fullscreen {
    animation-name: fullscreen;
    animation-duration: 1500ms;
}

.original {
    animation-name: original;
    animation-duration: 1500ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer id="foot">
      <a href="#top"><h2>Let's Go</h2></a>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `<script>` tag in your HTML?

Comment: You must create `<footer>` before using `getElementById`

Comment: The code is working. https://jsfiddle.net/L37y1ank/1/

Comment: By the way you can do it with only css!!

Comment: If the linked canonical isn't the issue, ping me and I'll reopen, but almost sure that it is

Comment: thank you lbra, I fixed the error by moving the script tag in my code(which does exist) to the bottom of the body instead of in the head

Comment: Seems like you missed the <script> tag in your html. Also make sure you placed your script bottom of the HTML just before closing body tag. Check the duplicate marked one, which explain all the possible reasons. BTW your code is working fine check the jsfiddle which Roy is shared, happy coding, all the best for your school competition